# Exception when calling methods from console

Tags: c#

I am making a console app thats gonna invoke methods from strings, now that part is ok but when it comes to the parameters i need some help

This is the code, this is from the `static void main(String[]args)`

```
                 //Gets the variable for the void/Method
                 string void_name = Console.ReadLine();

                 //Making the type in this case its 'Program'
                 Type type_ = typeof(Program);

                 //Making the route with the string 'void_name'
                 MethodInfo method_ = type_.GetMethod(void_name);

                 //Getting optional parameters 
                 Object[] obj = new Object[] { "" };
                 foreach (ParameterInfo _parameterinfo in method_.GetParameters()) 
                 {
                     obj[0] = Console.ReadLine();
                 }
                 foreach (string obj_string in obj)
                 {
                     Console.WriteLine(obj_string);
                 }

                 //Calling the functions
                 method_.Invoke(type_, obj); <-- this is were i get the exception

             }
             catch (Exception exception_loop)
             {

                 Console.WriteLine(exception_loop.Message);
                 Console.Clear();
             }
         }

    }

    public void helloworld(string something_) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\tHeisann: " + something_);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

How about your method declaration be like this:

```
public static void helloworld(string something_)
```

You are calling from a static method.

Answer (score 0):

You pass in the wrong object in your [MethodInfo.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) call. The first parameter needs to be the object instance the method has to be invoked on. In your case that is `this` (aka an object of type Program). You passed in a reference to a Type class and that has no instance method called `helloworld`.

```
   //Calling the functions
   method_.Invoke(new Program(), obj);
```

A small change, big difference...

Comment: he cant do that in this example rene since its from static main.his type is right,its just his method declaration.

Comment: @terrybozzio youi're right, it is either having an instance of the type (I fixed the bug in my answer) or make the method static. Now we wait if your answer (+1) is correct or mine :-)